# Mac OS X 10.6.7 and IntelliJ 9 editor problem

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I just updated Mac OS X to 10.6.7 and now IntelliJ 9 has gone nuts. When I try to open a file in IntelliJ it opens but only shows a couple of characters of the file. Looks like a font problem so I blew away the ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea90 directory and did a restart. Still broken. Messed around with Preferences... still nothing. Anyone else having or had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you delete [IDEA caches](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181)?

Comment: rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea90
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea90
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/IntelliJIdea90
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea90

Comment: Did you try to change the font in Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts to something different?

Comment: Yep. Now trying to build a bootable external drive from an old backup... now I'm getting desperate!

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line. I think this is an isolated problem. Isolated to **my** system. I talked to 2 other developers using Mac OS X 10.6.7 and IntelliJ 9. They aren't seeing a problem. I restored an older backup [Mac OS X 10.6.6 and IntelliJ 9] and everything worked fine. Then, upgraded to  Mac OS X 10.6.7 ... invisible fonts were back. Odds are I simply had a ticking time bomb for some MacPorts or package the I had previously installed.